# Java GUI with Database

Tags: java, derby

I'm trying to create a simple GUI program that has an access to my derby database.

```
public void viewRecord(int id)
{

    try{
        GET_RECORD = "SELECT * FROM record where id = ?";

        s = c.prepareStatement(GET_RECORD);
        s.setInt(1, id);
        r = s.executeQuery();
        rs = r.getMetaData();

        System.out.printf("%-15d%-15s%-15d%-15s%-15s",r.getInt(1), r.getString(2), r.getInt(3),r.getString(4),r.getString(5));




    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dbase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Whenever the function is called, I get

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.

What's wrong with my syntax? Thank you :)

EDIT:
Full error message(?)

> Jan 31, 2016 12:16:15 AM database.project.Dbase viewRecord
>   SEVERE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
>       at database.project.Dbase.viewRecord(Dbase.java:95)
>       at database.project.viewItem.btnViewActionPerformed(viewItem.java:107)
>       at database.project.viewItem.access$000(viewItem.java:6)
>       at database.project.viewItem$1.actionPerformed(viewItem.java:39)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: ERROR XJ121: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.checkForValidCursorPosition(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientResultSet.checkGetterPreconditions(Unknown Source)
>       ... 41 more

Comment: 1. First get rid of the Swing code since your problem has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with invalid SQL statement and you will want to simplify your problem to solve it. 2. Post your **full** error message.

Comment: Also which line throws the exception?

Comment: sysout stament  throws exc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `next` call.

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    rs.getMetaData()...
}
```

Quote from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call >to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes >the second row the current row, and so on.

Comment: My reputation is too low. :( Sorry. I still upvoted though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `next()` into `while` loop and use `rs` not `r` like this `rs.getInt(1)`...:

```
 while(rs.next()){
  rs = r.getMetaData();
  System.out.printf("%-15d%-15s%-15d%-15s%-15s",rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getInt(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that you only need to loop if you need to view multiple records. A thousand thank yous.

Comment: Oh. Nvm, fixed it. Had a problem with the initialization. Thank you again. :)